# Justified text with UITextView and NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm trying to put a justified text for a `UITextView` with `NSMutableAttributedString`, the `NSMutableAttributedString` is composed of different `NSAttributedString` because I need bold and regular font, so I append different `NSString`, this is my `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```
NSAttributedString *one = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"abc" 
                                                          attributes:boldDict];
NSAttributedString *two = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" def" 
                                                          attributes:regularDict];
NSAttributedString *three = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" ghi" 
                                                            attributes:boldDict];

NSMutableAttributedString *string = 
 [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:one];
[string appendAttributedString:two];
[string appendAttributedString:three];
```

I have tried this:

```
[self.text_view setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified]
```

and this:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyles = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyles.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified; 
Dictionary *attributes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyles};
```

and apply this to NSMutableAttributedString, but neither works. how i can do?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same problem by specifying transparent background color for the NSAttributedString.

Looks like a bug in the UILabel code which should render simple NSAttributedString like NSString.

Xamarin.iOS example:

```
var paragraphStyle = new NSMutableParagraphStyle();
paragraphStyle.Alignment = UITextAlignment.Justified;
var attributedText = new NSAttributedString(simpleString,
                         paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
                         backgroundColor: Color.Transparent.ToUIColor());
myLabel.AttributedText = attributedText;
```