# NSAttributedString Justify aligement for UITextView cause app crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I want to make some part of my text in `UITextView` to be right justified.

I use `NSAttributedString` and use the code below for justifying the text:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle * justifiedStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
justifiedStyle.alignment= NSTextAlignmentJustified;


NSDictionary *firstAttributes = @{
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor],
                                     NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: justifiedStyle
                                };

[myString appendAttributedString:
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myNewString attributes:firstAttributes]
     ];
```

but it is not working and cause an app crash.

I saw some related topics like:

[Justified text with UITextView and NSMutableAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430475/justified-text-with-uitextview-and-nsmutableattributedstring)

and others as well. 
Someone said that if I use `firstLineHeadIndent` it should work. Others suggest using 'addTab' but none of them are working for me. Does anyone work with this in iOS7 ?

**Edit**
Regarding to crash log:

Actually it goes to `main.m` file and select the `return` line but green color and at the End of green line writes:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, Address= 0x8)
```

No comments apprearing on the output box.

Comment: What's the crash error message?

Comment: above code is working fine show the crash log?

Comment: It is not showing any crash log in my out put box, is there any way other than output box to get the crash log?

Comment: When I change 'NSTextAlignmentJustified' to 'NSTextAlignmentRight' it do not crash.

Comment: For the BAD ACCESS, try to enable Zombies